# Is it good style to use a case expression on a Unit value just to use guards?

Tags: haskell

What is the recommended way of testing several boolean expressions ?

I've been using this:

```
case () of () | test1 -> value1
              | test2 -> value2
              | otherwise -> value3
```

Is this good style ? is there a prettier way ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This pattern can be simulated with a function — for instance, `cond` from [Control.Conditional](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cond/latest/doc/html/Control-Conditional.html#v%3acond):

```
signum x = cond [(x > 0     ,  1)
                ,(x < 0     , -1)
                ,(otherwise ,  0)]
```

I can’t call it particularly beautiful, though.

---

In next GHC we [will be able to use multi-way if](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4359), hooray! (just found it out)

```
f t x = if | l <- length t, l > 2, l < 5 -> "length is 3 or 4" 
           | Just y <- lookup x t        -> y 
           | False                       -> "impossible" 
           | null t                      -> "empty"
```

Answer (score 7):

This is an idiom I see pretty often since Haskell lacks a proper syntax for a case without matching. To make my intentions clearer, I usually intentionally match `undefined`:

```
case undefined of
  _ | foo       -> bar
    | baz       -> quux
    | otherwise -> chunkyBacon
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also pattern match on your series of expressions inside a tuple

```
case (test1,test2) of
  (True,_) -> value1
  (_,True) -> value2
  _        -> value3
```

Comment: Yes, I knew that idiom from Erlang and its guard expressions restriction :) But that gets really ugly when the number of guards increase...